# Window title not showing up in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

So I am learning Kivi library and I am trying to set a title for a window by using `Window.set_title("Password manager")` however, the title just doesn't appear.

My full code:

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout 
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput 
from kivy.core.window import Window



class Main_menu(GridLayout): 
    def __init__(self, **var_args):  
        super(Main_menu, self).__init__(**var_args) 

        #setting window size
        Window.size = (500, 700)

        #setting window title
        Window.set_title("Pasword manager")




# the Base Class of our Kivy App 
class MyApp(App):  
    def build(self):

        return Main_menu() 


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Window` title is overwritten by the `App` title. You can set that title using:

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Pasword manager'
        return Main_menu()
```